# Cakephp 4 MySQL on hosted environment

Tags: database, connection

I have created a Cake solution locally and have uploaded this on my hosting provider's environment. It runs MySQL. I have full access to the respective database but of course not the MySQL main database. If I understand the situation correctly, there are multiple databases in the same environment used by other clients on different domains that I would never see.
The provider has disabled the ability to manage user rights in PHPMyAdmin. Through an admin panel I was able to create a user that is granted INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT and DELETE rights. However, with the specified datasource parameters in appl_local.php, I get the message below when I try to add a new user to the database through the users/add page. For security reasons I have marked the name of the user with asterisks in the code below.

1. Could it be that I have to more specifically explain on which database we are trying to execute this?
2. Is there a way to tell the system to always specify the database when asking for a table? For example "SELECT * FROM database_name.users" instead of just "SELECT * FROM users"? I ask this because in the message below it does not specify which database was accessed when this error was raised, only the command, the user, the table and the source code file and line number.
3. Or is there some schema that needs to be specified when working in a shared environment?

`2021-01-07 10:39:00 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user '******'@'localhost' for table 'users' in /home/multigra/domains/multi-grade.nl/public_html/content/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/MysqlStatement.php on line 39`

```
    'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /*
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        'port' => '3306',

        'username' => '******',
        'password' => '******',

        'database' => '******',
        /**
         * If not using the default 'public' schema with the PostgreSQL driver
         * set it here.
         */
        //'schema' => 'myapp',

        /**
         * You can use a DSN string to set the entire configuration
         */
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an overight from my end. I had specified the location of information a little too much in order to learn about specifying databases when data is spread over different databases. Because the production environment connects to a different database, the requested table was not found at all. The error "SELECT command denied to user '******'@'localhost' for table 'users'" did not point me in that direction. I thought it was a permission issue. Instead, the table was not found in the database and that's why the SELECT statement failed.